# missing vertical scroll within ListView xaml uwp

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

am new in UWP and need to do a navigation drawer using `SplitView`, so my basic layout structure is mentioned below. The problem is that I don't have vertical scroll for list items, maybe I miss some params, any help is appreciated.

```
 <SplitView
    x:Name="MySplitView"
    DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
    IsPaneOpen="True"
    CompactPaneLength="50"
    OpenPaneLength="280">

    <!--navigation drawer-->
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel
            Background="Gray">

            <StackPanel>

                <ListView
                    x:Name="DrawerListOptions"
                    SelectionChanged="MySelectionChanged"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                                    <TextBlock
                                        Text="{Binding Title}"
                                        FontSize="18"
                                        Margin="5,0,0,0" />


                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>

    </SplitView.Pane>

    <!--page stuff-->
    <SplitView.Content>
         <!--page code-->
    </SplitView.Content>

</SplitView>
```

Comment: Simple thing to remember, Stack Panel kills scrolling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At first, change `StackPanel` to `Grid`

```
    <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView"
               PaneBackground="Gray"
               DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
               IsPaneOpen="True"
               CompactPaneLength="50"
               OpenPaneLength="280">

        <!--navigation drawer-->
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <ListView x:Name="DrawerListOptions"
                            SelectionChanged="MySelectionChanged"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
            </Grid>

        </SplitView.Pane>

        <!--page stuff-->
        <SplitView.Content>
            <!--page code-->
        </SplitView.Content>

    </SplitView>
```

If this does not help try to setup `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`

**UPDATE**

If you want to place some elements above `ListView` use `Grid.RowDefinitions`

```
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel>
                    <!--Other elements-->
                </StackPanel>

                <ListView x:Name="DrawerListOptions"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          SelectionChanged="MySelectionChanged"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
            </Grid>

        </SplitView.Pane>
```

How it works:

[image]

Comment: yes it works but if I need to put `Button`(toogle button) on top, then `ListView` I must use this `StackPanel` to put elements in desired order, because `Grid` just put my button in the middle  and xaml doesn't provide any `below` param

Comment: as @Vagif Abilov mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12690041/5414507) this method does't work as expected, if remove `Grid.RowDefinitions` scroll works but list overwrite the button

Comment: fixed it,so remove `Grid.RowDefinitions` and set  `Margin="0,myButtonHeight,0,0"` to my `ListView' and now list is below button, not the best solution but is working. I'll mark your answer as the right one anyway.

Comment: @VasileDoe I don't know what you're doing wrong, but I haven't any problem. I updated answer and put image

Comment: Sorry. How to create the GIF animation?

Comment: The key here is to have the last row Height="*" and not Auto. If it's auto, the scrollviewer won't be rendered.

Answer (score 3):

StackPanel has already a scrollviewer. Just set height in the listView and the scroller will come up. Without height listview doesn't understand that it goes at of the screen. This way you won't need to use a Grid. It worked for me!